# load datatables with Ajax with a parameter filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

i have a texbox in my webpage in which the user enters a value and clicks search .Based on the value entered the datatable should show results.I get the results of a query in JSON  and I am trying to use Ajax to load the datatables but I am not sure how to pass the id and get the results to load the table.Does it have to be in a form?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                     $('#search').click(function() {
                       var id  = $('#sun').val();
                        var request = $.ajax({
                           url:          'suns_data.php?job=get_sun',
                           cpage-content false,
                           data:         'sun=' + id,
                           dataType:     'json',
                           contentType:  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                           type:         'get'
                         });
                         var table_sun = $('#table_sun').dataTable({
                            "ajax": "suns_data.php?job=get_sun",
                            "columns": [
                              { "data": "col1" },
                              { "data": "col2"},
                              { "data": "col3" },
                              { "data": "col4" },
                              { "data": "col5"}
                            ],
                            "aoColumnDefs": [
                              { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }
                            ],
                            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                            "oLanguage": {
                              "oPaginate": {
                                "sFirst":       " ",
                                "sPrevious":    " ",
                                "sNext":        " ",
                                "sLast":        " ",
                              },
                            }
                          });
                     });  
                   });
```

Comment: Data loading is working correctly ?

Comment: // #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table_sun.search( this.value ).draw();
} );

Comment: yes data loading is working correctly without passing parameters

Comment: try my above code. and let me know if its working

Comment: on search button you dont need to make an ajax call again , as we are already getting bunch of data first time. Just apply the filter. it will be enough

Comment: actually i want the data table to show data only after the search button is clicked with the selected id filter applied

Comment: do one thing then,  you can filter the data on the click even of search button . like   $("#mySearchBtn").click(function () {   table_sun.search( $('#sun').val() ).draw();   });

Comment: do i have to initialize the data table first outside the click?can you please edit what I have and give me the full code. I am new to Ajax and do'nt understand completely.

Comment: no , no need to initialize again .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116149/discussion-between-user1721546-and-punit-gajjar).